# Attoparsec optional parser with Maybe result

Tags: haskell, option-type, attoparsec

I have an [Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) parser like this:

```
myParser :: Parser Text
myParser = char '"' *> takeWhile (not . isspace) <* char '"'
```

I want to make this parser optional so I get a function that returns `Just txt` if the parser matches and `Nothing` else, i.e. a function of the signature:

```
myMaybeParser :: Parser (Maybe Text)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems to me that you keep asking questions and accepting your own answers, which by the way are posted at the exact same time of the question.

Comment: @rubik Yes, this is a built-in feature of StackOverflow and it is actively encouraged to use it! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @rubik Please note that I will happily accept other answers. I had several self-answered questions where someone came up with a better answer and I happily accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`option`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v:option) and the Applicative instance of `Parser` for this:

```
-- Make a parser optional, return Nothing if there is no match
maybeOption :: Parser a -> Parser (Maybe a)
maybeOption p = option Nothing (Just <$> p)
```

You can then use it like this:

```
myMaybeParser = maybeOption myParser
```

Comment: Iirc, there's also an Alternative instance, in which case you can use the optional function.